# Which type of continuous BLE Scanning in Android 5.1 Save the power?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

In android  5.1 is BLE scanning is filter parameter is responsible for save battery? if yes then how it will work?

is there any other way to get good scanning result with low power?
I used SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER but some time device is not detecting in this mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter parameters in Android *may* save power. It depends on the chip set. Some support vendor specific capabilities such as the ability to filter advertising packets in the controller as opposed to higher up the stack in the host (travelling up and down the stack consumes power).

See https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//devices/Android-6.0-Bluetooth-HCI-Reqs.pdf

SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER will cause the scanning interval to be relatively long (i.e. how long to wait in between scans or how frequently/infrequently to scan) and is essentially how it can save power. The downside as you've found is that the probability of missing an advertising packet you wanted to catch is higher.

Comment: Thank you !! I got both point as you explained , but  is there any good way to save power with efficient scan result??

Comment: If by efficient you mean "giving a very fast beacon detection time" then there's no magic answer. Lots of scanning means lots of radio use means power consumption. As I said, filter parameters may help since at least then only advertising packets you are interested in will travel all the way up the stack. Without this, all packets received go right up the stack to be rejected by application code and this is much more expensive than filtering in the controller.

Comment: Could you accept the answer then please? Thanks :-)